# Magento 2 modal-popup not opening second time

Tags: magento-2.1, modal-popup

I am calling my modal widget from an external .js file on link click which is working fine for the first time but when I cancel the modal and click the same link again it is not opening. Also when I include the js code in my file it works fine. Any help?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: yeah it started working I was making a silly mistake, btw thank you for responding.

Comment: Could you Please post code here so we can help?

Comment: @akshay billore what was the error you were making?